# To check if webview's shouldInterceptRequest will get called or not?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am having an android app where i use webview to load an html file that has a call to a javascript function as follows:

java:

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dog.html");
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:sayhello('how are you')");
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(getWebViewClient());
```

html:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somelibrary.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<script>
function sayhello(text){
somelibrary.somefunc(text);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Now in my application I am intercepting the request coming the js library like below:

```
 private WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {
return new WebViewClient() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, final String url) {}
}}
```

What I need is ,that I want to check whether the method shouldInterceptRequest will be called or not because in some of my request ,it's not getting triggered.
i want to show some message if the request is not intercepted.
Is there any way to know priorly whether the method  shouldInterceptRequest will be triggered or not?

Answer (score 0):

shouldInterceptRequest  : This callback is invoked for a variety of URL schemes (e.g., http(s):, data:, file:, etc.), not only those schemes which send requests over the network. This is not called for javascript: URLs, blob: URLs, or for assets accessed via file:///android_asset/ or file:///android_res/ URLs.

[Refer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

Comment: are you sure about that?because the above code is a working code.It failes only during certain scenario which i am not able to figure out.Hence the question.
P.S:The js library fetches information from the server.

Comment: Yes,i . am sure you can check the developer page ( 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest) )